# Leaflet: map.locate set maxZoom dynamically

Tags: leaflet

It is easy to track a users position and show a position marker with Leaflet

```
_map.locate({
    watch: true, 
    setView: true, 
    maxZoom: 13,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
})
```

and some code in the locationfound callback.

However, the user might wish to zoom to a differed level, but when the position maker gets updated the map always zooms back to the value set in the locate maxZoom option.

Is there a way to change the maxZomm value dynamically depending on the zoom level the user has chosen?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after digging a bit in the source it is just as easy as this:

Listen to the **zoomend** event

```
_map.on('zoomend', _changeLocateMaxZoom);
```

and then update the locateOptions maxZoom

```
function _changeLocateMaxZoom(e) {
    if (_map._locateOptions) {
        _map._locateOptions.maxZoom = _map.getZoom();
    }
}
```

Leaflet is a well designed library.